# Passing a Constructor into into base class constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, function-pointers

I have a base class that needs to initialize a variable that will change depending on which child is calling the constructor.
So,

```
public class TestClass<T> {
    T variable;
    string parameter;

    public TestClass(passed_in_constructor) {
        variable = passed_in_constructor(parameter);
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

**EDIT: Let me rephrase the question. Below is an alternate way of doing what I am trying to do and I can better explain the error and the problem**

I currently have the following class:

```
public class Test<T> {
    SqlConnection conn;
    T genericGuy;

    public Test() {
        conn = ...this is initialized properly
        genericGuy = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), sqlConn);
    }
 }
```

When I run this however, I am getting an Error. My 'T' is actually an interface and so the error says that there is no constructor defined in this interface.

I want the constructor under the interface to get called though...how can I do this?

Comment: Let the child instantiate it. Why try to do it in the base class?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Maybe `public abstract class TestClass<T> {
        readonly T field;
    
        protected TestClass(T passed_in_constructor) {
            field = passed_in_constructor;
        }
    }` Could you give an example to show how this is supposed to be used?

Comment: basically the 'variable' is going to be different types of controllers. I need to be able to instantiate whichever one is being passed in

Comment: This is really starting to sound like an XY problem.

Comment: why can't you pass class as `T`? why interface?

Comment: I can't pass the class because it is an internal class

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `Func`. Let the child decide what to do with that variable:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    T variable;
    string parameter;

    public Foo(Func<string, T> action)
    {
        variable = action(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: But that string is `null`?

Comment: pretend the string isn't null haha!

How do I pass in action if it's a constructor? What does it looks like for the calling class? Sorry, very new to this

Comment: @LaurAchnid `public Bar() : base(str => ConvertStrTo<T>(str))` something like that. You'd better learn from articles and books rather that QA site.